# Angular 7 adding embed code into components

Tags: javascript, components, angular7

I am trying to get a third party instagram embed code (which holds javascript) into one of my html's components.

Is there a way that I can do so in a clean way? Not really understanding on how to implement this. Would appreciate it if someone could give me a solution!

```html
<div class='embedsocial-instagram' data-ref="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>

<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js;
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://embedsocial.com/embedscript/in.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document, "script", "EmbedSocialInstagramScript"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a script tag to the end of your page.

```
<other-html>
    ....
</other-html>

<script>(function(d, s, id){var js; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "https://embedsocial.com/embedscript/in.js"; d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);}(document, "script", "EmbedSocialInstagramScript"));</script>
```