# Embedding Checkout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I'm trying to embed the checkout of GiftUp on my angular site however not show when I run my HTML page.

```
<div class="gift-up-target" data-site-id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-platform="Other"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(g, i, f, t, u, p, s) {
        g[u] = g[u] || function() {
            (g[u].q = g[u].q || []).push(arguments)
        };
        p = i.createElement(f);
        p.async = 1;
        p.src = t;
        s = i.getElementsByTagName(f)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(p, s);
    })(window, document, "script", "https://cdn.giftup.app/dist/gift-up.js", "giftup");
</script>
```

Am I correct in just putting this inside my .html or should I split the script up from it.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue

Comment: Aha!!!! This similar issue seemed to work.  If anyone else is looking for the solution...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252491/angular-7-adding-embed-code-into-components